# Django. How to change the input class of a Built-in form

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to change the class of the django Built-in form PassowrdChangeForm. This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
class FormChangePassword(PasswordChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'old_password': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'new_password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'new_password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

and just in case it is useful info, I'm using the built-in password_change view like this:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change
from forms import FormChangePassword
url(r'^change_password/$', password_change,
            {'template_name': 'sisacademico/change_password.html',
             'post_change_redirect': 'password_changed/',
             'password_change_form': FormChangePassword},
                name='change_password'),
```

It doesn't work, the form doesn't get the class 'form-control', any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`PasswordChangeForm` is not a `ModelForm` so `Meta.widgets` is not working here.  You have to set widget's `attrs` in the `__init__()` constructor:

```
class FormChangePassword(PasswordChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormChangePassword, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in ('old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2'):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
```